# Splitting the Name and Changing the First Letter to Upper Case

Tags: vbscript

How can I write my full name where the first letter is in upper-case and the rest is lower-case for example:

```
Michael Jonson Bech
```

I have this so fair:

```
option Explicit


Dim Name,fName

Name = Split(InputBox("what is your name"))


Dim var 

For Each var In Name
    'var=UCase(Left(var,1))
    LCase(var)
    UCase (Left(var,1))

Next

fName = Join(Name)

WScript.Echo("you name is :  " & fName )
```

Comment: That is not vb.net - please tag correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String functions like UCase do not modify the operand, but return a modified copy. For Each v gives you copies of the array's elements named v.

So you need something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Dim a : a = Split("mIchael jOnson bEch")
WScript.Echo Join(a)
Dim i
For i = 0 To UBound(a)
    a(i) = UCase(Left(a(i), 1)) & LCase(Mid(a(i), 2))
Next
WScript.Echo Join(a)
```

output:

```
cscript 34629546.vbs
mIchael jOnson bEch
Michael Jonson Bech
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like VB6, in which case something like :

Dim Name as string

Name = InputBox("what is your name")

Name = StrConv(Name, vbProperCase)

Comment: It isn't VB6 it's VBScript which doesn't support strongly typed variables everything is `Variant`. Not sure if VBScript supports `StrConv()`, pretty sure your thinking of VBA.